# HttpsUrlConnection. setInstanceFollowRedirects(false) seems not effective

Tags: java, httpsurlconnection

everybody.I'm using the web crawler to query the user's integral in some web sites.But i get into trouble.First of all ,let's focus on this picture:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JjBMO.png)

As you can see,the first request ,it's response code is 302,that is this page will be redirected to another page.Now ,look at my code,the login method:

```
private JuneyResults login(String url, String param) {
    JuneyResults results = new JuneyResults();
    HttpsURLConnection connection = null;
    int contentLength = param.getBytes().length;
    try {
        URL requested = new URL(url);
        connection = (HttpsURLConnection) requested.openConnection();
        connection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", UA);
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Cookie", map2String(mCookies));
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length",String.valueOf(contentLength));
        DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
        os.write(param.getBytes());
        os.flush();
        os.close();
        switch (connection.getResponseCode()) {
            case HttpURLConnection.HTTP_MOVED_PERM:
            case HttpURLConnection.HTTP_MOVED_TEMP:
                updateJuneyAirCookie(connection);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        results.setException(e.getMessage());
    } finally {
        if (connection != null)
            connection.disconnect();
    }
    return results;
}
```

Ok,I have set the request header properties we exactly need.And passed false to setInstanceFollowRedirects method.The expected response code is 302,the same as we see in the picture,but,it's still returns 200.I don't think there are some logic error in my code,however,Facts are facts,it DO returns 200,in this picture,the page has been redirected to the third page!!So,i hope that some of you can help me to find out what's the reasons are.

Comment: sorry, setInstanceRedirects should be setInstanceFollowRedirects

Comment: NB `setDoOutput(true)` sets the request method to POST. You don't need to do that yourself.

Comment: @EJP could you explain how can setDoOutput set method to POST while it's just setting field in `URLConnection`, the parent of `HttpUrlConnection`: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/net/URLConnection.java#URLConnection.setDoOutput%28boolean%29 ?

Comment: @AntonMalyshev Because that's what it says in the Javadoc.

Comment: yes,you are right,but i think this should not be the key point in this question.@EJP